# How to fetch checked values in bootstrap multi select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ho can i bring the checked values in bootstrap multi select. [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/pL4hg76b/3/)

```
<input type="text" id="addRow" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add" />
<form id="form1">
<div style="padding:20px">
<select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
<option>asdad</option>
<option>ere</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if I understood the question right, but the behaviour is not changed by the fact that you use bootstrap. So, you can simply do

```
$('#chkveg').val();
```

This will simply return an array containing the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

In the [FAQ part of the documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#faq):

> Using jQuery, how to get the selected options dynamically?

```
//  get all option elements
$('#example option:selected');

//  get all option element values
$('#example option:selected').map(function(a, item){return item.value;});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chkveg :selected').each(function(i, selected){   chkveg_val[i] = (selected).text(); });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dave17/6xq8sp7t/

i hope it will be helpful